# Can you use multiple ssh keys in the same location?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keygen

One creates an ssh key by the command

```
ssh-keygen
```

and then copy/paste the virtual key into the virtual server's authorized keys file. Normally, the key's contents are output into `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`.

My problem is that I want some keys to be password protected, and one not to be. How could I have several keys in several locations? How all keys have to be placed in `id_rsa.pub`? If not, what do I name this?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just pass the `-f` option to `ssh-keygen` or type a different file name when prompted. Then, when copying the public key to the remote `authorized_keys` file, use the corresponding `.pub` file. `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` are the default locations but there's nothing magical about those locations. I recommend keeping all the keys in the `.ssh` directory, however, to make them easy to manage and locate.

When you run `ssh`, it will try all the keys that have been loaded into the agent. You can specify a particular key with the command line option `-i` or with the `IdentityFile` directive in `~/.ssh/config`.

Comment: So, if you save a key in `~/.ssh/locationA.pub` and in `~/.ssh/locationB.pub`, location B will locate this key because...it's in the `.ssh` directory? There's something here I don't understand

Comment: @ShanZhengYang No. The public key file is never used explicitly. You copy the public key to the `authorized_keys` file on the server, either with `ssh-copy-id` or by any other means.